# C# HTMLAGILITYPACK Extract href where innertext = "Last"

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

i want to extract the href of a html page with the HTMLAGILITYPACK.

This is the String on the WebPage:

```
<a class="smallfont" href="http://example.com/fasdfsd" title="I am a title">Last <strong>»</strong></a>
```

I tried this:

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr//td[@class='alt1']//a[@class='smallfont']//[@innertext='Last']")
```

But this isnt working.

I hope you guys can help me

Comment: `//tr//td[@class='alt1']//a[@class='smallfont' and starts-with(text(),'Last')]`

Answer (score 0):

Because you already have nodes, which contains links, you can do following:

```
var links = MyLinkNodes.Select(node=>node.Attributes["href"].Value).ToArray();
```